# audioplayers My button doesn't play sound in first click

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a button and when I click it plays click sound. In my first click it doesn't play the sound, second click plays the sound and if I wait 3-4 sec and click the button no sound again. But always print CLICKED.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyButtonState createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  AudioCache _audioCache;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioCache = AudioCache(
        prefix: "assets/sounds/",
        fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        print('CLICKED');
        _audioCache.play('buttonClick.wav');
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 80,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: Center(child: Text('CLICK ME')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ive tried the answer code. There is no sound problem but :)
when page init in my first click console output is

```
D/WSP     (16110): Reusing soundId1 for /data/user/0/com.example.myapp/cache/buttonClick.wav is loading=false xyz.luan.audioplayers.WrappedSoundPool@bfc7a44
V/AudioTrack(16110): start: server read:-8418  cumulative flushed:0  client written:0
```

and other click outputs like this

```
I/flutter (16110): CLICKED
V/AudioTrack(16110): start: server read:-12627  cumulative flushed:0  client written:0
I/flutter (16110): CLICKED
V/AudioTrack(16110): start: server read:-14030  cumulative flushed:0  client written:0
I/flutter (16110): CLICKED
V/AudioTrack(16110): start: server read:-15433  cumulative flushed:0  client written:0
I/flutter (16110): CLICKED
V/AudioTrack(16110): start: server read:-16836  cumulative flushed:0  client written:0
```

Comment: What are you testing on? How big is your wav file? I have no problem with your code.

Comment: On my own phone. 5kb. I don't see a problem either. I guess it could be a phone related situation.

Comment: It's possible. Check my answer for a way to improve performance that may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
_audioCache = AudioCache(
  prefix: "assets/sounds/",
  fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer(
    // set mode to LOW_LATENCY for better performance with short audio files
    mode: PlayerMode.LOW_LATENCY,
  )..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP))
    // pre-cache the audio file so it doesn't have to load on first call
    ..load('buttonClick.wav');
```

Comment: thanks it works but i think i get errors or something :) i updated my question. Are they problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting errors when working with AudioPlayers flutter package.

Go to pubspec.yaml file and load all the sounds in your assests. For example

```yaml
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/note1.wav
    - assets/youngpro.mp3
```